# Access to a protected constructor in Java

Tags: java, subclass, protected

If I have a class A and its subclass B.

```
package washington;
public class A{
       protected A(){}
}

package washington;
public class B extends A{
      public B(){super();} // it works
      public static void main (String[] args){
      A b = new A(); // it does work.
       }
}
```

The class A has a protected constructor, but I cannot access the constructor in B. I think it is a rule, however, I cannot find a webpage describing this situation.. All that I saw mention `protected` can be accessed from subclass, same-package.... e.t.c.

```
package california;
public class A extends washington.A{
    public static void main (String[] args){
       new washington.A(); // it does not work.
    }
}
```

I wonder if this is because I use IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4.. compiler is javac 9.0.4

Comment: You can't assign an instance of `A` to `B`. Other than that, it works fine: https://ideone.com/VRha9m

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private This may help clear up any confusion.

Comment: In sub class reference you can not assign to super class object

Comment: why not: `B b = new B();`? (in any package)

Comment: @shmosel  ah it is my mistake... I changed what I really am facing... still it does not work.

Comment: You can't even reference `A` from another package because the whole class is package-protected. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel Thank you again. ..sorry over and over... it is public... i wonder if this is because IntelliJ IDEA.... (I changed a question again)

Comment: What's the relevance of `B`?

Comment: New to me: it seems that protected methods are not generically accessable from the sub class, but only via the super keyword. I.e. you can access the constructor via `super()` and a `protected method a()` via `super.a()`, but not directly (`new california.A()` or `new california.A().a()`). So if this is a problem you should explain why you cannot make the constructor public and why you have to use the super class in your main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you have your classes in different packages. [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.2) says:

> If the access is by a simple class instance creation expression `new C(...)`, or a qualified class instance creation expression `E.new C(...)`, where `E` is a Primary expression, or a method reference expression `C :: new`, where `C` is a ClassType, then the **access is not permitted**. A protected constructor can be accessed by a class instance creation expression (that does not declare an anonymous class) or a method reference expression **only from within the package in which it is defined**.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A{
    protected A() {
        System.out.println("hello from A");
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public B() {
        super();
        System.out.println("hello from B");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        A b1 = new B(); // you can either do this
        B b2 = new B(); // or this
    }
}
```

Try running the program and you will see the expected result printed on console.

Comment: really nice answer.

Comment: ahhh..... I understand the situation.
I set the class names same..... then it does not work

Comment: you got it... :)